# Usar apache como cliente

Tags: python, apache, selenium

¿Alguno de ustedes sabe si es posible que un servidor APACHE descargue información de otro servidor? (Cómo si fuera una computadora normal)

Pd. Yo uso bots para intentar descargar pero supongo que el problema está o en mi herramienta de bots (selenium) o en qué no sea posible por alguna restricción configurada por defecto.

Un abrazo y buen fin de semana

Comment: No tengo claro como quieres que funcione tu apache. ¿Deseas un software que te permita descargar información (simulando un navegador) de algunos sitios.? Siendo así no es posible usarlo de esa manera; apache es un servidor web, no un cliente. en este caso te sugiero buscar herramientas de Scrapping..

Comment: Estoy haciendo scrapping jajajaj con Selenium en Python, la cuestión es que en pruebas locales mi bot descarga los archivos sin problemas utilizando Firefox como navegador ... Se supone que en el server debería funcionar igual pues tengo instalado Firefox y mi librería de Selenium

Comment: Entiendo, Te recomiendo preguntar sobre el problema que tienes en selenium en el servidor, describiendo lo que tienes y donde aparece el problema.

Comment: El problema básicamente es que no puedo descargar archivos aunque Selenium me lo permita y no tengo una interfaz gracia para ver qué es lo que sucede

Comment: El selenium no guarda logs.?=

Comment: Si no tienes GUI y tu script depende de la UI del explorador de archivos para descargar el archivo entonces te recomiendo que cambies tu codigo para que obtengas la URL del archivo y lo descargues por wget a través de CLI. Otra manera es que si tu servidor es Linux puedes crear un display virtual, con pyvirtualdisplay. https://www.vionblog.com/selenium-headless-firefox-webdriver-using-pyvirtualdisplay/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me temo que apache no dispone de dicha opcion, excepto que tu idees un script o python que se apoye de apache

Comment: Si es posible... Es extraño pero a mí me funcionó